# JqueryUI access modify drag function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get access and modify this function (second one) in jqueryUI. I have tried everything. What I want to do is to add something in the function. I know it is possible and I need to do something like this :

```
var snapIt = $.ui.draggable.prototype.drag;

$.ui.draggable.prototype.drag = function() {
    console.log("hello"); // exemple of a thing I want to add

    // Now go back to jQuery's original function()
    return snapIt.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

On top it will get the function add in console "hello" and then continue normally with the rest of the jQuery function. But I just can't find this function. I know this doesn't work: **$.ui.draggable.prototype.start** and dozens of others I tried.

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "snap", {

    start: function( event, ui, i ) {

    click.x2 = event.clientX;
        click.y2 = event.clientY;

        var o = i.options;

        i.snapElements = [];

        $(o.snap.constructor !== String ? ( o.snap.items || ":data(ui-draggable)" ) : o.snap).each(function() {
            var $t = $(this),
                $o = $t.offset();
            if (this !== i.element[0]) {
//...........
```

I don't want the **drag: function(event, ui) {.....** I need to modify the function because I use ui.position = {left..... and it make the snap method not work. The only way was to change the drag method. I know it work because I tried manualy. But changing the library might be problematic for futur dev.

Don't know if I am clear but basically I want the path to **$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "snap", {//stuff});** in jqueryUI library

Thx in advance

Comment: Is there some reason you do not want to enable the `snap` option in `draggable`?

Comment: I did enable the snap but I use the ui variable which is also used by snap so or the snap works or my special drag works not the 2. 
I want the dialogbox to snap each other but I have a Dashboard that is rescalable so the mouse doesn't work well when I drag if I'm not on scale(1). So I want the snap but also in the same time the dialog to follow my mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different sources of behaviors that are called on the different events in jquery-ui, each with its own structure.

First you have the "private" functions, that are defined on the prototype and that are called directly on native events. These are on `$.ui.draggable.prototype` and begin with a _ character. For example you have `$.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseDrag` function. 
These are called directly and are the ones triggering the events. They are not directly accessible from the options.

Then you have the plugins functions. These are the ones that are added using **add**. Basically what **add** does is that it sets functions to be called on the events that are accessible via the options. And these plugins callbacks are called if their corresponding option is true. The structure goes like this:

- Each plugin is an object that defines a callback for different
  events. The events available are the same that are accessible in the options. For draggable, you have **start**, **drag** and **stop**.
- These callbacks are pushed in arrays contained by
  $.ui.draggable.plugins object, in which each property is one of the available event.
- A function goes through the event array and validates if the plugin
  should be ran based on the option set.

Once the plugins are done, the options callbacks are called. These are the ones that you set in the options.

So depending what ou want to modify, you can either change the prototype:

```
$.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseDrag
```

Or you can add a plugin. Like this:

```
$.ui.plugin.add( "draggable", "customPlugin", {
drag: function(event, ui, draggable){
console.log("I'm the custom plugin");
});
```

Or you can modify snap plugin. This one is a bit more complicated, and much less reliable since the functions are stored in arrays and not in an object, and they are added. The structure goes like this:

- Each property key is an event, and every property is an array of
  arrays.
- Each of the array first element is the name of the option associated
  with the callback, that is the second element of the array.

So the drag callback associated to snap is  **$.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2]**, because it's the third callback that's been added to drag event. $.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][0] is the string "snap", which is used to check if the option was set to true. And the callback is **$.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][1]**. So you can modify it like this:

```
$.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][1] = function(){
    console.log("I'm the modified plugin");
}
```

If you want a better control, you can iterate through **$.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag** array and check the first element to make sure you modify the proper plugin. 
Obviously, as you tried, you need to store the original callback if you want the behavior to work.

See here how this goes:

```js
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "customPlugin", {
  drag: function() {
    console.log("%c I'm a custom plugin", 'color: blue');
  }
});

var _temp = $.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][1];

$.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][1] = function() {

  console.log("%c I'm the modified snap plugin drag callback", 'color: red');
  _temp.apply(this, arguments);
}

$('div').draggable({
  snap: true,
  customPlugin: true,
  drag: function() {
    console.log("%c I'm the options callback", 'color: green');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>Drag me</div>
<div>Or me</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks AAAAA lot the " $.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins.drag[2][1];" did the trick, the 2 other ways didn't because I use the ui variable which is also used by snap so or the snap worked or my special drag worked not the 2. Now, it works really good thx to you. But can you tell me a bit more how you did to find the [2][1] thing ? So next time I don't have to ask. Anyway thx a lot

Comment: see edit, I've detailed the structure of $.ui.draggable.prototype.plugins

Comment: Thx a lot now I understand now, I accept your answer right away